# hash key "#" stripped from ussd code in "tel:" links on html pages

Tags: html, ussd

Good day all.
I have a simple link on a webpage, in where the user can call an USSD number:

```
<a href="tel:*111*2#" class="phoneCallButtonLink">*CLICK HERE AND CALL *111*2#</a>
```

this is pretty straight forward; now, if I test it on desktop browser, it popups an alert asking me if I want to call (with skype) the number ***111*2#**, and thats ok.

with my Android phone (S Note 3), when testing this page, the phone (or something) **stripped out the last "#"** (only the last) from the link, resulting in a call to ***111*2**.

does anyone has experienced this? or knows how to prevent this?

Comment: Try to replace # with %23.

Comment: for some reason, the last hash encoded is seen as a %23

Comment: have you try my ans ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with no luck, I try to encode directly and in various way with js... thelast hash is stripped, sounds like some kind of prevention by the phone to automatically deal ussd codes....

Answer (score 13):

[Use URL encoding for special character in a UR](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)L. For example `#` equals `%23`

This worked for me:

```
<a ng-href="tel:%23 224">#224</a>
```

As you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `Uri.encode("#")`
For example `String number = "tel:*111*2" + Uri.encode("#");`

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.loadData("<a href=\"tel:*111*2#\" class=\"phoneCallButtonLink\">*CLICK HERE AND CALL *111*2#</a>","text/html", "utf-16");
 webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

 private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
    if(url.startsWith("tel:")) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse(url.replace("#","%23")));
       startActivity(intent);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way to display the USSD in dialer

```
<a href="tel:*111*2%23" class="phoneCallButtonLink">*CLICK HERE AND CALL *111*2#</a>
```