# href=“tel:” # symbol in number is not shown

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want this number "*3*123#" to be inserted as the tel number.
but upon clicking link from android devices the # sign omitted and the number to be dialed is *3*123.I have also tried all of these codes but none of them could do the job.

```
<a href="tel:*3*123#">

<a href="tel:*3*123&num;">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890866/hash-key-stripped-from-ussd-code-in-tel-links-on-html-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
<a href="tel:*3*123%23" >Call us!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without JS, by using'&#35', which is the equivalent to &amp => & for the # symbol.

I.e:

```html
<a href="tel:*3*123&#35;">tel:*3*123&#35;</a>
```