# Add # sign in tel uri using Url_launcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

In flutter app i am using Url_launcher dependency to open phone application with content to dial using following function
Url_launcher.launch("tel:\*5*250#" ).
It does open the application but # symbol is not dialed in there else everything works ok ... Any workaround to include # ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43889379/217408

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this issue only on Android devices. It works on iOS.

You need to use [URL encoding for special character in a URL](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

So `#` equals %`23`

This will work `launch('tel:\*5*250\%23');`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872008/742298) helped me.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and safest way is encode the mobile number typed by user and pass it through

> Uri.encodeComponent(numberTypedByUser)

Like this.

```
launch("tel:" + Uri.encodeComponent('*5*250#'));
```