# Issues with URL launcher package in Flutter

Tags: url, launcher

I use URL_launcher to send sms but with some android phone I have "+" who is changed in space " ". With my galaxy s7 I haven't this issue.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737159/add-sign-in-tel-uri-using-url-launcher) who speak about `Uri.encodeComponent(numberTypedByUser)` but I tried but without result.

I tried to change + by \%2B (it's work for my galaxy s7 but not for other smartphone).

Gradle is UTF_8.

```
 localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
```

Here is my code:

```
  var Phone_Number = '$indicator$number';
   var body_text="\%2B";    //  \%2B is like +

    var uri = 'sms:$Phone_Number?body=$body_text' ;
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    }
```