# How to fix where numbers after the "#" sharp sign are not entered in the dial pad (url_launcher)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically any number is returned and displayed normally on my dial pad, yet numbers after "#" sign are not displayed. For ex:

This works fine:

```
 switch (operator) {
    case "A":
      {
        
        return "*1332222";
      }
      break; 
}
```

This doesn't:

```
switch (operator) {
case "B":
      {
        
        return "*133#22222";
      }
      break;
    }
```

Comment: use single quotes?

Comment: This is likely an issue/inability of `url_launcher`, not a problem with the OP's implementation. Might be a good idea to open an issue on the package? or do more googling, I haven't done any myself.

Comment: @ChapleyWatson Same thing, doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I'm leaning to your opinion too.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `#`?

Comment: @Fawaz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737159/add-sign-in-tel-uri-using-url-launcher

Comment: @ChristopherMoore it's for a USSD code to work with the mobile network operator.

Comment: @ChapleyWatson Thanks for the reference. Surpassingly Stackoverflow didn't suggest that to me (or maybe i missed it).

Comment: @Fawaz hopefully it solved your issue?

Comment: @ChapleyWatson Yes perfectly.